# Override Topmenu.php in magento

Tags: magento, overriding

I'm trying to override the _getHtml function in Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu magento class

I've created a new module in app/cod/local/MyModulo/Opage

My congig.xml is:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MyModulo_Opage>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MyModulo_Opage>
</modules>
<global>
<blocks>
    <page>
        <rewrite>
            <html_topmenu>MyModulo_Opage_Block_Html_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
        </rewrite>
    </page>
</blocks>
</global>
```

My class is:

But when I test it, the category top menu doesn't appear. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MyModulo_Opage>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MyModulo_Opage>
</modules>
<global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_topmenu>MyModulo_Opage_Block_Page_Html_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Call rewrite block class path `app>code>local>MyModulo>Opage>Block>Page>Html>Topmenu.php`

```
 <?php
 class MyModulo_Opage_Block_Page_Html_Topmenu extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved it. The problem was that I missed a folder in the folder tree.

Comment: after extend front side not display menu